# How to solve error placing a node with a picture in a slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I would like to ask how to solve the compiling error of this beamer code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\graphicspath{{_figs/}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=10}

\title[GdR (U.1.1.)]{Introduction to GdR}
\author[Manhatan]{John Doe\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
Course of Statistics\\
}
\date{Octubre 2021} 

\begin{document}
    \metroset{block=fill}
    
    \begin{frame}[t]{}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    %--- Next Frame ---%
    
    \section{Definitión} % (fold)
    \label{sec:definition}
    \begin{frame}[t]{Analogy}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \visible<1-2>{\node at
                [xshift=5cm, yshift=0cm](current page.center)
                {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,]{VS.jpg}}; }
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    %--- Next Frame ---%
    % section definition (end)
\end{document}
```

The file VS.jpg is this:

[image]

The error at compiling is:

`Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.`

Comment: It's probably the node syntax. Try `\node at ([xshift=5cm, yshift=0cm]current page.center)...` instead

Comment: As Juan told you, the opening parenthesis before `[xshift` is missing

Comment: @JuanCastaño Now it compiles. Thank you. However, I am not able to place the image at any point in the slide. For example, `\visible<1-2>{\node at
          ([xshift=1cm, yshift=-3cm]current page.west)
          {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,]{VS.jpg}}; }`. I cannot change the position of the .jpg image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here:

1. The syntax for shift w.r.t a node is:

> ```
> \node at ([xshift=5cm, yshift=0cm]current page.center)...
> ```

so you must include the options for shifting **inside** the node name parentheses.

2. If you want to access the nodes created in the page `(current page)` you should add the options `remember picture, overlay` to your `tikzpicture`.
3. Unrelated, but there is a warning `Token not allowed in a PDF string...`. This is because you are including LaTeX in the author name: `\\`, `\vspace`... To avoid this warning you can use the macro `\texorpdfstring`.

The corrected code could be:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\graphicspath{{_figs/}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=10}

\title[GdR (U.1.1.)]{Introduction to GdR}
\author[Manhatan]{John Doe\\\texorpdfstring{\\[0.5cm]}{--} % LaTeX is not allowd in the pdf author tag
Course of Statistics
}
\date{Octubre 2021} 

\begin{document}
    \metroset{block=fill}
    
    \begin{frame}[t]{}
      \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    %--- Next Frame ---%
    
    \section{Definition} % (fold)
    \label{sec:definition}
    \begin{frame}[t]{Analogy}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \visible<1-2>{\node at
                ([xshift=2cm, yshift=0cm]current page.center)
                {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,]{example-image}}; }
            % added for showing the change
            \visible<3>{\node at
                ([xshift=-2cm, yshift=0cm]current page.center)
                {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,]{example-image}}; }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    %--- Next Frame ---%
    % section definition (end)
\end{document}
```